# How to set image for checkbox on validation in angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular5, angular7

I am trying to set image for checked and unchecked checkboxes on validation condition.checked checkbox should be checked image. Unchecked check box should be unchecked image.But not working.I have used angular 6 reactive form method

Comment: Do you want to make checkbox as image or what is your expectation?

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition of **control-invalid** to:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate [formGroup]="fg">

      <div class="main" [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid': fg.get('bUnits').at(i).invalid, 'ng-valid': fg.get('bUnits').at(i).valid}" formArrayName="bUnits" *ngFor="let unit of businessUnits; let i = index;">
          <p>Unit {{ i+1 }}</p>

              <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" [value]="unit.value">
              <label> {{unit.name}} </label>

      </div>

      <br>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      <p>You have selected all checkboxes ::: {{ fg.valid }}</p>
</form>
```

```css
.main.ng-touched.ng-invalid input[type=checkbox]+label::before {
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Red_checkbox-unchecked.svg/768px-Red_checkbox-unchecked.svg.png)!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
}

.main.ng-touched.ng-valid input[type=checkbox]+label::before {
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/Red_checkbox-checked.svg/600px-Red_checkbox-checked.svg.png)!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
}

.ng-invalid{
  color:red;
}
.ng-valid{
  color:blue;
}
```

And check your **css class**, when I change it to **.control-invalid** then it works. I don't know css much.
Hope it helps

Comment: Images should be come from css

Comment: I have updated my question and see for example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2u8ebm?file=app/checkbox-overview-example.css

Comment: Check it @Krithik

Comment: Can you apply checked and unchecked  image for checkbox?

Comment: I think you can work this way: **Make 2 css class for 2 state** ,  in ngClass use **fg.get('bUnits').at(i).value**

Comment: I think you can work this way: **Make 2 css class for 2 state** ,  in ngClass use **fg.get('bUnits').at(i).value**

Comment: Can you edit my stackblitz? that will be very useful.

Comment: You can use ng-valid and in-invalid class names.

Comment: I tried but not working...Can you check my Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-form-validation-2rx4wd?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Not working: In your code..first i selected all the checkboxes then i unchecked one checkbox afterthat all the checkboxes are red color..why it is coming like that?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-form-validation-fgtnl4?file=app/app.component.css

Comment: the **formArrayName="bUnits" or formGroup** auto implements validation itself, so change **ng-invalid** class and **ng-valid** class to other name

Comment: Can you do from typescript..without change this class names? is it possible?

Comment: As per my project requirement i can not add css class name..I can use only ng-valid and ng-invalid. So can you use typescript inside  this.fg = this.fb.group({ .... or other method?

Comment: I can't find how to change it. Btw, if you don't want to use default behaviors of **FormGroup** then just don't use it.

Comment: Without  use formgroup how can i validate it?

Comment: Use **FormControl** for each field.

Comment: Phat Huynh :I am new in angular so can you edit my stackblitz using form control?